# How to set up and use SVN on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, svn

I have install svn on ubuntu 9.10. But when I try to use svn to checkout code for an open source project, i get this error:

```
$ svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
svn: Berkeley DB error for filesystem '/home/svn/repos/valgrind/db' while opening 'nodes' table:
Cannot allocate memory
svn: bdb: Lock table is out of available locker entries
```

What steps to do I need to take to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the exact same problem. Looks like a server issue to me. Check valgrind's website, see if it's already been reported. If not, contact them and give them the error you're receiving.